# How do I pass an object to a default form instance

Tags: vb.net

I understand its possible to open the "default instance" of a form in vb.net by calling NameOfTheForm.show()

How do I pass an object to the default form instance so i can work on the object and use it to populate the forms Text boxes?

I've tried to add a parameter to the frmNames New method but I'm not sure how then to open the form. The old style instantiate an object works:

```
        Dim DetailsForm As New frmOrder(oOrder)
        DetailsForm.Show()
```

But I'm used to using the :

```
frmOrder.show
```

syntax.

Should I use the top method or should I use the bottom method and have a public property on the form to accept the Object?

Have a missed a better method of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to unlearn this horrible practice.  The default instance feature was only added to vb.net to give vb6 programmers a shot at converting their programs.  What you call "old style" is not old, it is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah! OK.  When I saw it was added in later version of vb.net but not in the original versions I thought it was a new way of doing it.  It saves having to handle a form opening up multiple times when somone presses a button (if you dont check it if it exists first).  Something else i've learnt today. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calling method should use your first option

```
'Careful about declaring this in a sub, because when that sub ends, the form might get closed.
'It might be best to declare this as an instance var (aka form-level var)
Private DetailsForm As frmOrder

'this could go in an event handler, or anywhere
DetailsForm = New frmOrder(oOrder)
DetailsForm.Show()
```

You will need to add a constructor to your `DetailsForm`:

```
Private _oOrder as OrderType

Public Sub New(oOrder As OrderType)
     'Best to save it to a private instance var and process it during Form_Load
     _oOrder = oOrder
End Sub
```

Then when your `Form_Load()` runs, it can use your private instance var to fill your `TextBox`es, like you want.

A second, but less eloquent approach would be to add a public property to the form and after you call `.Show()`, you can assign a value `DetailsForm.OrderObject = oOrder`, and then process the object that was passed-in.

The constructor approach is better because it can be "compiler checked"

Comment: Another way is to override `Show()` method which would 1) accept oOrder; 2) set it to the variable; 3) call base `Show()`. Same for `ShowDialog()`

Comment: @MikeMakarov - thanks - thats an interesting approach. Sometimes I forget about overriding methods.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you really feel you must use default instance.

In Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.myObject = New Coffee("Breakfast Blend", 7)
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

In Form2

```
Public myObject As Coffee
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = myObject.Name
    TextBox2.Text = myObject.ID.ToString
End Sub
```